# Jest spyOn makes the function 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm building a React Native application with TypeScript and I write my unit tests using Jest.

I'm currently writing the unit tests for the loading screen:

```
export class LoadingScreen extends Component<Props, object> {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    const { dispatch, navigation } = this.props;
    getToken()
      .then(key => {
        if (typeof key === "string") {
          getBootData(dispatch)
            .then(() => navigation.navigate("HomeScreen"))
            .catch(err => {
              alert(err);
              // TODO: Hide the splash screen, after componentDidMount finished.
              navigation.navigate("LoginScreen");
            });
        } else {
          // TODO: Hide the splash screen, after componentDidMount finished.
          navigation.navigate("LoginScreen");
        }
      })
      .catch(() => navigation.navigate("LoginScreen"));
  };
  // ... render() n' stuff.
```

As you can see after the component mounts, I check if there is a token. And depending on the token I load sync the app with the server (in `getBootData`) and navigate to the respective screen - either `Home` or back to the `Login`.

Here is the test that I wrote for this life cycle method:

```
describe("life cycle methods", () => {
  describe("componentDidMount", () => {
    const props = createTestProps({});
    const wrapper = shallow<LoadingScreen>(<LoadingScreen {...props} />);
    const getTokenSpy = jest.spyOn(secureStoreFunctions, "getToken");
    const getBootDataSpy = jest.spyOn(bootDataFunctions, "getBootData");

    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.resetAllMocks();
      getBootDataSpy.mockResolvedValueOnce(true);
      wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
    });

    it("should call getToken", () => {
      expect(getTokenSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it("should call getBootData", () => {
      expect(getBootDataSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

My aim was to spy on the `getToken()` method to see if it was called.
But the problem is that this leads to the error:

```
● LoadingScreen › life cycle methods › componentDidMount › should call getToken

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

      17 |   componentDidMount = () => {
      18 |     const { dispatch, navigation } = this.props;
    > 19 |     getToken()
         |     ^
      20 |       .then(key => {
      21 |         if (typeof key === "string") {
      22 |           getBootData(dispatch)

      at LoadingScreen.componentDidMount (app/screens/Loading/LoadingScreen.tsx:19:5)
      at Object.beforeEach (app/screens/Loading/LoadingScreen.test.tsx:39:28)
```

*BTW:* The test for `getBootData` also fails.
I thought spyOn was supposed to leave the original implementation of the function intact?  But apparently it exchanges it with undefined :(

**Extra Information**

This is how `getToken` looks:

```
import { getGenericPassword } from "react-native-keychain";
export const getToken = (): Promise<boolean | string> =>
  getGenericPassword().then(
    creds => (typeof creds === "boolean" ? creds : creds.password)
  );
```

I also have a simple mock for React Native Keychain's `getGenericPassword` in a `__mocks__/` folder adjacent to my node modules so that the function automatically get's mocked by Jest in other tests that require this function:

```
const token = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
const credentials = {
  username: "session",
  password: token
};

export const setGenericPassword = jest.fn(
  (username, password) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true)) // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
);

export const getGenericPassword = jest.fn(
  () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(credentials)) // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
);

export const resetGenericPassword = jest.fn(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true))); // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

It might be that these two mocks somehow stack and cause the undefinedness? The thing that speaks against this is that I do not have a global `getBootData` mock, which - as mentioned above - fails similarly.

What is going on? Why does spyOn cause the function to become `undefined`?

Comment: 1. you are rendering before you set up your spies
2. you are setting up spies on `secureStoreFunctions` is a module specific reference, meaning if you `import * as secureStoreFunctions ...` from two different files, I'm pretty sure you get two different objects. It's better to `jest.mock` the module.